# Lipschitz constant of the exponential map

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lipschitz-functions, geodesic

Let $M$ be a smooth Riemannian manifold and let $p \in M$. Suppose $r \ll \text{inj}(p)$ (the injectivity radius at $p$) and fix $t \in (0,r)$ then define the map
$$ T_pM \ni v \mapsto \exp_p(tv) \in M$$
I know this map is a diffeomorphism. How can I estimate its Lipschitz constant?

If I take $v_1, v_2 \in T_pM$ and I consider the geodesics $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ starting at $p$ with initial speed $v_1$ and $v_2$ respectively, it would be enough to prove
$$ \frac{d}{dt} d \left(\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t)\right) \le |v_2-v_1| $$
to conclude that the Lipschitz constant is bounded by $t$. But even if I consider the differential of the distance given by
$$ \frac{d}{dt} d (\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t))= \langle \dot{\alpha_t}(d_0), \dot{\gamma_2}(t) \rangle - \langle \dot{\alpha_t}(0), \dot{\gamma_1}(t) \rangle $$
where $d_0 = (\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t))$ and $\alpha_t$ is a unit speed geodesic connecting $\gamma_1(t)$ to $\gamma_2(t)$, I only obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} d (\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t)) & = \langle \mathcal{P}^{\gamma_2}_{t \to 0}[\dot{\alpha_t}(d_0)], v_2 \rangle - \langle \mathcal{P}^{\gamma_1}_{t \to 0}[\dot{\alpha_t}(0)], v_1 \rangle \\
& = \langle \mathcal{P}^{\gamma_2}_{t \to 0}[\dot{\alpha_t}(d_0)] , v_2 \rangle -\langle \mathcal{P}^{\gamma_2}_{t \to 0}[\dot{\alpha_t}(d_0)],  v_1 \rangle + \langle \mathcal{P}^{\gamma_2}_{t \to 0}[\dot{\alpha_t}(d_0)]-\mathcal{P}^{\gamma_1}_{t \to 0}[\dot{\alpha_t}(0)],  v_1 \rangle \\
& \le |v_2-v_1| + \langle \mathcal{P}^{\gamma_2}_{t \to 0}[\dot{\alpha_t}(d_0)]-\mathcal{P}^{\gamma_1}_{t \to 0}[\dot{\alpha_t}(0)],  v_1 \rangle
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{P}^{\gamma}_{t_0 \to t_1}[v]$ is the parallel transport of $v \in T_{\gamma(t_0)}$from $\gamma(t_0)$ to $\gamma(t_1)$ along $\gamma$.

It is clear to me that the second summand must go to $0$ as $t \to 0^+$ and this would imply the result for small $t$. But I have not idea of how to prove that!

Comment: What is $\mathrm{inj}(x)$? Thanks

Comment: It is the infectivity radius at $x$. Basically I am only considering a neighborhood of $0_p \in T_pM$ where the exponential map is a diffeomorphism onto some open neighborhood of $p$.

Comment: Yes, as long as you assume an upper sectional curvature bound. This essentially is the content of Rauch Comparison Theorem.

Comment: I have never heard about this result, could you please expand your comment?

Comment: Did you ever try to read do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry"? He covers Rauch's theorem and his book is my favorite introduction to R.G.

Comment: Yes, I also really like that book! I will look for the theorem on it!

Comment: Actually no. I also posted the question on mathoverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335878/lipschitz-constant-of-exponential-map but I never obtained a satisfactory answer. Everything seems to work in local coordinates but I was not able to translate everything in the Riemannian metric

Comment: In my mathoverflow question you see that my manifold is actually compact so sectional curvature is bounded. I am not into Riemannian geometry as I was 2 years ago so I should study this stuff again before applying Topogonov theorem. If you are able to write a clear answer I would be grateful!